# TPS55340 boost converter output voltage dropping under high load

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, boost

I am trying to make a high-power audio amplifier circuit consisting of the [TPS55340](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvsbd4e/slvsbd4e.pdf?ts=1672425444339) as a boost converter IC to boost a battery's voltage from 14.4 (12-16.6 V) to ~19 V, to allow higher output power from the audio amplifier and keep a steady voltage throughout the total battery discharge cycle.

However, I cannot pull more than 1.4 A from the battery before the output voltage on the TPS55340 begins to drop significantly (~16.2 V where Vin = 15.52 V). The effect is even worse as the battery discharges more.

Requirements for the boost converter design:

- 19 V Vout
- 3 A peak output current
- Smallest PCB footprint design and layout
- Lowest possible ripple on Vout

The battery is a custom made 4S/1P 21700 pack consisting of the [Samsung 50E](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0481/9678/0183/files/samsung_50e-2_1d3ffd2c-0e25-4f97-9f01-15cc1539f57f.pdf?v=1663389721) cells. The associated BMS is able to output 6 A of continuous and 8 A non-continuous current, confirmed using low-value resistor loads. The cutoff voltage for overdischarge is 12 V and the cutoff for overcharge is 16.6 V. I'm certain that this battery pack is not the issue. I've even used a bench power supply rated up to 30 V, 6 A on Vin and the voltage drop on Vout still persists.

I've cleaned the PCB from flux and other residue using IPA alcohol, as I was informed that this could have an impact on the circuit performance. Sadly, Vout still drops significantly.

I've attempted to increase the C10 capacitor value, all the way up to 2200 μF and still no luck.

BoM:

- [D1](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/581-SD2114S040S8R0)
- [L1](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/652-SRP7028A-100M)
- All other parts are generic. All the capacitors are rated for at least 25 V and are low ESR. The ceramic caps have XR7 quality. The resistors are all within 1% of their rated values. Both resistors and ceramic caps are 0603 (imperial) packaging.

Schematic:

[image]

PCB layout (**C9 footprint is open and not used in this design**):

[image]

After countless hours of head-scratching, I feel that I screwed up what appears to be a simple and straightforward boost converter design. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked input current vs output current? It is a good bet that the inductor is saturating or not operating at a high enough frequency to transfer sufficient energy to the output. Or it could be too high frequency. Try changing the FREQ resistor.

Comment: I would indeed double check the inductor and the higher ESR caps.

Comment: You should have a little over 5A peak inductor current with 3 A out, which should be OK (Isat on this inductor is 6 A).  The average input current should be about 4.9 A, also OK.  Have you looked at the switch node waveform to see if you have excessive jitter or instability when the output voltage drops?

Comment: @PStechPaul I was able to monitor both in and out current, and the output current spikes as the Vout voltage drops (as expected). I’ve attempted different switching frequencies above 600KHz but all appear pose the same result, with slightly different ripple on Vout. I can’t select a frequency too low as per the data sheet it would require a higher value inductor and decoupling capacitors which isn’t suitable for the layout restrictions of this design.

Comment: @John D I haven’t probed the switch pins but I did probe the outputs of the audio amplifier powered by the boost converter to analyze the clipping. When Vin voltage was above 15.6 V the clipping was controlled and there didn’t appear to be any instabilities from the amp or the boost converter (the Vout still dropped to ~17.52 V where Vin was ~15.95 V). When Vin was under ~15.6V, the boost converter was starting to oscillate when the amp was clipping. As a result, the amp just went into a shutdown state and restarted when Vout increased to the expected value.

Comment: Your inductor Isat and peak current are on the edge (but not over the edge) for 3 A output current.  You should have no trouble at 2 A of output current. Your layout isn't terrible, so I'd scope the switch node to see what's happening when the output voltage starts dropping. Was the part hand-soldered down?

Comment: @John D Here is the SW node under normal operation: https://ibb.co/2hFfv1p. And here is the SW node after Vout drops to ~15 V: https://ibb.co/wLW3bzq. Vin was ~15.12 V at the time of capturing these. And yes, the IC with all other associated components were hand-soldered. Using TI’s WEBENCH to create a circuit based on this chip, I noticed that with my given design requirements, only a 2.2uH inductor was suggested but it’s Irms was 7 A and Isat was 12 A. All other components are what they should be. Could it be that the inductor current rating I’m currently using is too low for this design?

Comment: Your design should allow much more than 1.4 A of input current before having an issue.  The schematic and layout look OK.  That leaves 2 possibilities:  The power pad underneath the device is not well soldered to the board causing issues at higher current (my best guess at this point) or the compensation is off causing instability (but you'd likely see that at lower currents, so probably not).  You could try a load transient test at lower currents to see if the response looks marginally stable.

Comment: Also, probably would have helped to keep AGND and power ground separate, returning the compensation and feedback divider to AGND, then connecting AGND to power ground at the power pad as shown in the datasheet.  But getting a good solder connection to the power pad by hand soldering is difficult, so I'm still guessing that's the problem.

Comment: Did you already tried smaller caps on the in and outlet? 470uF is pretty big and give thereby their own problems.

Comment: The power pad is dual layered and there are vias connecting the layers. I chose this design so that I can use a soldering iron to heat the solder through the bottom pad into the top pad. However, I have no concrete indication that the power pad was correctly soldered. All I know is that the IC started to heat up significantly when the iron was on the bottom layer pad. Are there any other means to confirm that the power pad has been correctly soldered?

Comment: @RemyHx I haven’t tried any caps below 100uF. Should I use smaller value electrolytic or ceramic decoupling caps? The data sheet doesn’t appear to clarify this.

Comment: @garrett_ader i would start using a ceramic if possible. Or similar low ESR and with short leads.

Comment: Although you cleaned the flux with IPA, there might still be some ionic contaminants such as salt, that can be removed by scrubbing with detergent, hot water, and hot air to dry it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

I did an LTspice simulation of a simple boost converter to see what the waveforms might look like. This is at 1MHz and 30% duty cycle. Everything looks OK. Easiest to check might be at the switch, making sure the signal goes solidly to GND without desaturation. That is the violet v(n002) trace.

[image: Simple Boost Circuit]

Can you get a cleaner trace for your switch node? Can't really tell anything with so much noise.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I tried scoping different nodes connected to the SW pin and this appeared to be the best I could get when Vout drops: https://ibb.co/z49rmMf. Now, I also discovered that changing the load reduced the voltage drop on Vout until the inductor began to saturate. So this issue may be specific to the load of the boost converter (2x TPA3128D2 Class D amps). I will have to perform some more tests to be sure but if that is the case I will likely open a new question about it.

Comment: It looks like there is some power line AC noise, and the converter seems to be operating in some sort of burst mode. It would help to run a sweep frequency high enough to see details of the switching waveform. And you may need to rig up a special clip for the scope probe. What do the input and output DC waveforms look like? And also try a plain resistive load.